# How Kubernetes NodePort Type Service load balance to pod

Tags: kubernetes

I still have a question about Kubernetes NodePort service.

NodePort: Exposes the service on **each** Node’s IP at a static port (the NodePort). A ClusterIP service, to which the NodePort service will route, is automatically created. You’ll be able to contact the NodePort service, from outside the cluster, by requesting :.

If I have two Node: nodeA and nodeB, and if I deploy an app only on nodeA then create a NodePort service, then can I use both nodeA and nodeB ips to access this service?

I had some tests, the result is no....

I did two kinds of tests:

**Test1:**

I deployed a deployment with two pods, one is on NodeA, another is on NodeB. then create a NodePort service to access it.
I can access the service by using both NodeA and NodeB ips. then I delete pod on NodeA, then try again. I found that I cannot access the service by using NodeA ip, but can access by using NodeB ip. After the pod is startup on NodeA, then I can access by using NodeA ip

**Test2:**

I deployed a deployment with only one pod, it is on NodeA. then create a NodePort service to access it.
I can only access the service by using NodeA ip but cannot by NodeB ip.

So my question is:

For the NodePort type, it can only be used that the pod/pods are on the same Node? If I use NodeA ip, service won't load balance the request to the pod on NodeB?

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: when you test against nodeA and nodeB are you doing it from some external "workstation" node or the nodes them selves ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I have two Node: nodeA and nodeB, and if I deploy an app only on nodeA then create a NodePort service, then can I use both nodeA and nodeB ips to access this service?
>
> I had some tests, the result is no....

In that case, it sounds very much like one of three things is not happening: you do not have `kube-proxy` running on all the Nodes, or the Nodes are firewalled off from one another in a very restrictive way, or you are not using a software-defined network (such as flannel, calico, etc).

That NodePort behavior is, to the best of my knowledge, implemented using `iptables` applied to all the machines, causing traffic received on port X of machine A to be effectively NAT-ed to one of the machine(s) where the actual Pods are running, back to machine A, back to the requester. It is `kube-proxy`'s job to install the initial `iptables` rules for doing that, and then subsequently keep them up to date as the Pods come and go from the cluster. One can observe the correct behavior by running `iptables -L -n -t nat` on a Node that **is** running `kube-proxy`, and observe the rules named for the various kubernetes services. They even helpfully include comments in the `iptables` rules, which I thought was nice

The firewalling case I think speaks for itself

I actually have never run kubernetes without a software-defined network, so I am not in a good place to offer troubleshooting steps (aside from: install flannel or calico and rejoice in their awesomeness). Perhaps others will be able to weigh in, if that is in fact your circumstance

Comment: Thanks Matt. Yes I found some of NAT configuration is not correct. I need to continue checking. Thanks! :)

Comment: awesome summary :-) as simple as that